# Why does a file read after calling lseek always return 0?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I cannot understand why a call to read after an lseek returns 0 number of bytes read.

```
//A function to find the next note for a given userID;
//returns -1 if at the end of file is reached;
//otherwise, it returns the length of the found note.
int find_user_note(int fd, int user_uid) {
    int note_uid = -1;
    unsigned char byte;
    int length;

    while(note_uid != user_uid) { // Loop until a note for user_uid is found.
        if(read(fd, &note_uid, 4) != 4) // Read the uid data.
            return -1; // If 4 bytes aren't read, return end of file code.
        if(read(fd, &byte, 1) != 1) // Read the newline separator.
            return -1;

        byte = length = 0;
        while(byte != '\n') { // Figure out how many bytes to the end of line.
            if(read(fd, &byte, 1) != 1) // Read a single byte.
                return -1; // If byte isn't read, return end of file code.

            //printf("%x ", byte);
            length++;
        }
    }
    long cur_position = lseek(fd, length * -1, SEEK_CUR ); // Rewind file reading by length bytes.

    printf("cur_position: %i\n", cur_position);

    // this is debug
    byte = 0;
    int num_byte = read(fd, &byte, 1);

    printf("[DEBUG] found a %d byte note for user id %d\n", length, note_uid);
    return length;
}
```

The variable length value is 34 when it exist the outer while loop and the above code produces cur_position 5 (so there are definitely at least 34 bytes after the lseek function returns), but the variable num_byte returned from function read always returns 0 even though there are still more bytes to read.

Does anyone know the reason num_byte always return 0? If it is a mistake in my code,  am not seeing what it is.

Just for information, the above code was run on the following machine

```
$ uname -srvpio
Linux 3.2.0-24-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 21 16:52:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Update:

- I upload the full code [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13414424/notesearch.c)
- This is the content of file that I try to read

> ```
> $ sudo hexdump -C /var/notes
> 00000000  e8 03 00 00 0a 74 68 69  73 20 69 73 20 61 20 74  |.....this is a t|
> 00000010  65 73 74 20 6f 66 20 6d  75 6c 74 69 75 73 65 72  |est of multiuser|
> 00000020  20 6e 6f 74 65 73 0a                              | notes.|
> 00000027
>
> $
> ```

Comment: There are no big errors in the code you posted, but you didn't post enough to tell what's wrong.  `lseek()` returns `off_t`, not `long`, but it's unlikely this is causing the problem.  As a matter of style, why multiply by -1 rather than just saying `-length`?

Comment: variable length is signed or unsigned ?

Comment: @Gene: I just updated the whole method. It actually written in book Hacking, the Art of Exploitation by Jon Erickson.

Comment: @qianfg: The file is opened in another method like this
`int fd = open("/var/notes", O_RDONLY);`

Comment: @LunarMushrooms: variable length is signed as shown in the edited code above

Comment: You surely are passing a value different from `-1` for `user_uid`, aren't you?

Comment: @alk the user_uid being passed here is 1000. I'm 110% positive about it.

Comment: As an aside, when we dubug a script using an IDE, we need to make sure that files should be sought in the same directory where the source lives. Else switch to command line and navigate to the binary directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the issue!!! I have to put `#include <unistd.h>` in order to use the correct lseek(). However I'm not sure why without including `unistd.h` it was compile-able though resulting in unexpected behavior. I thought that without including the prototype of a function, it shouldn't even compile-able.

The code was written in [Hacking: The Art of Exploitation 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593271441) by Jon Erickson and I have verified that in the book, there is no `#include <unistd.h>`.

Comment: My solution was just typecast: `lseek(fd, (off_t)length * -1, SEEK_CUR);` based on [Linux manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/lseek)

Answer (score 6):

If `length` is an unsigned type smaller than `off_t` (for instance, `size_t` on a 32-bit machine), then `length*-1` is going to be a huge value (somewhere around 4GB perhaps). This could be the problem. Storing the result of `lseek` into a `long` (again, if it's 32-bit) will apply an implementation-defined conversion, probably truncation, that leaves you with a small value again.

I see that your machine is 64-bit, but perhaps you're running a 32-bit userspace?

In any case, why not run your program under `strace` to see what system calls it's making? That will almost surely clear the issue up quickly.

Comment: I've uploaded the full code and the content of file it is reading. Any idea?

Comment: As alk said, you need to compile with `-Wall` and fix the warnings (the vast majority of which are *serious* errors) in your code. As it stands, this code has way too many errors in it for me to identify the source of the problem you're experiencing without me doing your work for you..

Comment: Thanks. I figured out that the same problem on my centos64 was caused by type mismatching. On my centos64, `off_t` is an alias of `long`. The use of `strace` reveals that the value of int `length` multiplying `-1`  is passed as a huge long integer, resulting in something like `lseek(3, 4294967288, SEEK_CUR)          = 4294967301`. The behavior of returning an integer beyond the end of file is specified in this [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html). After redeclaring `length` with type `off_t`, `lseek` works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

> With the initial variable length set to 34, the above code would
>   produce cur_position 5 (so there are definitely at least 34 bytes
>   after the lseek function returns)

This not necessarily is the case,  as one could seek around beyond the end of file without getting any errors.

See the excerpt from `lseek()`'s man page below:

> The  lseek()  function  allows  the  file offset to be set beyond the
>   end of the file (but this does not change the size of the file).

So one could very well receive a value form `lseek()`ing, which still points beyond the end of the file. So `read()`ing from this position will still return 0 (as is's beyond end-of-file).

---

Also I agree with R.., that taking more care in using the correct types (the types used by the methods used) isn't a bad idea.

---

**Update**: also you might take care to include all headers for system functions you call. To check for such I **strongly** recommand to use `gcc`s option `-Wall` to switch on all compiler warnings, they are for free ... ;-)

Comment: I've updated the code with the whole method so people get the better picture of the code

Comment: @wins I propose adding an initialisation like `int length=0` and a `printf()` logging `length` right after the outer `while` loop and prior to the call to `lseek()`.

Comment: the `length` has been initialized to 0 right before the inner while loop and in my initial post before I updated, I `printf` the `length` and it is 34

Comment: I've uploaded the full code and the file it is trying to read. Any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: Ok, I just bothered to download your code, added the missing function `fatal()`, commented out the include of `hacking.h`, created a test file and run the program. It's working, at least with my test file, which is similar to the dump in your update. It just differs by the number and values of the bytes between the two `0x0a`. Anyway, I **strongly** recommend you compile your code using `gcc`'s option `-Wall` to show all compiler warnings, and fix what's poping up. Then try again. The missing includes for functions returning something different than `int` (as `lseek()` is) mess up things.

Comment: Thanks for your clue. I've found the issue. Apparently I have to include `#include <unistd.h>` in order to get the lseek() function working correctly.